# Why do I need to enter my BitLocker recovery key every time after dual-booting Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bitlocker, dualboot

I recently got a new laptop and installed Windows 10 Pro. This laptop is UEFI-enabled and has BitLocker drive encryption. Following the advice of some other posts I first suspended BitLocker then rebooted into the UEFI and disabled both fast-boot and secure boot. Then I booted into my flash drive by holding shift while pressing the restart button (in Windows). I installed Ubuntu using the "Something Else" option and placed it on the partition I had previously created. Note that I left the default "Device for boot loader installation" option (i.e. the main boot partition shared by Windows). Now Grub is the main bootloader which is used to chain-load the Windows boot manager.

Well, now BitLocker requires the dang 48-number encryption key every time I start windows. Even if I just boot into Windows and immediately restart the key is still required. I've tried suspending BitLocker and rebooting, same story. I can boot into Linux just fine but every time I boot into Windows it requests the key.
I thought providing the key was intended to convince BitLocker to trust the current state?

What should I do? How do I get my machine to stop requesting the recovery key? Is there a better way to install Ubuntu for dual-booting? Did I miss a step? Maybe I should have placed Grub somewhere else?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It’s due to Secure Boot is disabled.  You have to disable BitLocker entirely not suspend it.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is occurring because you disabled Secureboot, Ubuntu should work fine with Secureboot enabled, and I expect that Bitlocker is complaining because it has been disabled.  What happens if you re-enable Secureboot?  (I'm not certain that turning Secureboot on will magically solve your problems, but if it does not stop Ubuntu working, its a good first step - you may or may not then need to get Bitlocker to recognise the change.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That's a good suggestion. Initially after install Ubuntu I had secure boot enabled but then I disabled it because BitLocker kept asking for a key every time. But disabling Secure Boot didn't solve the problem. In short the key was required whether Secure Boot was enabled or disabled.
I finally broke down and just stopped BitLocker entirely. Now my system is insecure because Microsoft makes it so difficult to keep it secure haha. Maybe I will try to re-encrypt the drive at some point.
If I turn BitLocker back on, will it ask for a key every time Grub updates?

Comment: Can someone please step me through the correct process for dual-booting on UEFI with BitLocker and secure boot then? Should I disable secure boot? What about fast boot? When should I suspend BitLocker? Which order? When should I re-enable them?

Comment: Just to clarify, re-enabling BitLocker after installing Ubuntu results in Windows asking for the key EVERY time Windows starts or reboots, regardless if Ubuntu was used or not in between sessions. I'd like to know the proper way to install Ubuntu / multi-boot to retain the security features without this happening. Thanks